# Custom GridSearch using Paramter Grid for Isolation Forest

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm building very basic unsupervised outlier detector with Isolation Forest. I wanted to tune the hyper parameters with GridSearchCV but GridSearch require labels  which I don't have. I decided to build custom made GridSearch which stores each computation in dataframe. Code looks like that

```
    params = {
    'n_estimators': [100,125, 150],
    'contamination': [0.0001, 0.001],
    'bootstrap': [True, False],
    'max_features': [1, 2]
}

clf = IsolationForest(random_state=42)
result2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['n_estimators','contamination','bootstrap','max_features'])
for g in ParameterGrid(params):
    clf.set_params(**params)
    clf.fit(X_train)
    pred_clf = clf.predict(X_test)
    unique, counts = np.unique(pred_clf, return_counts=True)
    result = (dict(zip(unique, counts)))
    result = result2.append([result,params], ignore_index=True)
```

However I ran into a problem when fitting because n_estimators require input to be integer not a list like in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `g` instead of `params` inside the loop.

Instead of this:

```
for g in ParameterGrid(params):
    clf.set_params(**params)
```

do this:

```
for g in ParameterGrid(params):
    clf.set_params(**g)
    ...
    ...
    result = result2.append([result,g], ignore_index=True)
```